# I am using Identity server 4 oidc authentication but when ever I apply authorize attribute then I am getting this - Token was not authenticated

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

This is the logging I am getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V2FZ.png)

Configurations -

```
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    var clientUrl = GetClientUrl(configuration);

    AddIdentityServer(services, clientUrl, configuration);

    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    });

    services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();

    AddCors(services, clientUrl);

    services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateOnlyJsonConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new TimeOnlyJsonConverter());
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews(); // Need views for IDserver pages

    services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddDbContextCheck<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddScoped<FluentValidationSchemaProcessor>(provider =>
    {
        var validationRules = provider.GetService<IEnumerable<FluentValidationRule>>();
        var loggerFactory = provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

        return new FluentValidationSchemaProcessor(provider, validationRules, loggerFactory);
    });

    // Requests for unknown pages will be passed to the SPA
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options => options.RootPath = "jsclient");

    // Customise default API behaviour
    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);

    return services;
}
public static void AddIdentityServer(IServiceCollection services, string clientUrl, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var idSrvConfig = new IdentityServerConfig(clientUrl);

    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetName().Name;
    string idServerConnectionString = configuration["DefaultConnection"];
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;

        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

        // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
        options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
    })
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(idSrvConfig.IdentityResources)
        .AddInMemoryClients(idSrvConfig.Clients)
        .AddInMemoryApiScopes(idSrvConfig.ApiScopes)
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddProfileService<AppProfileService>()
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
            options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;

            options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(idServerConnectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        });

    builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

}
```

Program file

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers()
        // This will apply identityserver policy for authorization to all controllers
        // so the user must be logged in via identityserver to call api
        .RequireAuthorization(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.AuthenticationScheme);

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

I am trying to implement identity server 4 authorization. My front-end is on React. When front-end application runs it's redirects to my razor login page. When I apply authorize attribute on a controller then I am getting this -

info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.LocalApiAuthentication.LocalApiAuthenticationHandler[7]
IdentityServerAccessToken was not authenticated. Failure message: invalid JWT token type

Comment: What does the token look like?

Comment: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQyRUMzOTI0MkRDNzE3N0NCRjA5MDk2MURDNEQyMzYzIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE3MDQ3MDEzNzEsImV4cCI6MTcwNDcwMTY3MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMSIsImF1ZCI6InNwYSIsImlhdCI6MTcwNDcwMTM3MSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6InV5V1pLOHJQNXJ0QUJfY0hWMUpIVWciLCJzX2hhc2giOiJ

Comment: the token seems to be internally encoded? are you generating it yourself? That token is not valid. Where do you get it from? Also, the token has no signature.